# Change css value using Angular

Tags: css, angular, progress-bar

In my project I'm using a "ngb-progressbar" element to draw a progress-bar.
To manually set the css for this bar I'm using this piece of code:

```
    ::ng-deep div.bg-success.progress-bar{
        background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(54,166,5,1) 0%, rgb(219, 238, 52) 100%) !important;
        background-size: 100% !important;
        background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
    }
```

In my TS code I need to set nynamically the value of background-size attribute and to do this I'm looking for a method to access to the element with "::ng-deep".
Removing "::ng-deep" changes have no effect.

Any idea to access my element style via TS code by using ::ng-deep ?

Comment: why not just use NgClass https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass

Answer (score 0):

Use the following HTML

```html
<div class="container" [class.someStyle]="yourCondition">
  <ngb-progressbar></ngb-progressbar>
</div>
```

So that you can use the following SCSS

```scss
.container {
  &.someStyle {
    ::ng-deep div.bg-success.progress-bar {
      // Your new style
    }
  }
  ::ng-deep div.bg-success.progress-bar {
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(54,166,5,1) 0%, rgb(219, 238, 52) 100%) !important;
    background-size: 100% !important;
    background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
  }
}
```

This is the cleanest solution at your disposal. The other solution involves manually changing the HTML with the help of vanillaJS or maybe the `Renderer2`, which are kind of meh.